# Is it possible to auto restart a Kubernetes/Openshift pod only if the first start was successful

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I wonder if it is possible to use container restart policy `"always"` or `"onFailure"` only if the pod has min. one clean start?

Something like this:

```
first start -> failed -> never start again

first start -> ok -> "some error" while running -> restart
```

thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with Kubernetes/OpenShift built-in controllers. If you need custom behavior you could create a custom resource and a corresponding controller (operator). For more information consider [Custom Resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/)
 and ["Extend the Kubernetes API with CustomResourceDefinitions"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/) in the Kubernetes docs.